Произношение сочетания согласных «жд» в слове «дождь»
В данном отрывке определите, как следует произносить в слове дождь сочетание согласных жд: Дай отдохнуть на уступе скалы! Дай расколоть это зеркало мглы! Чтобы лохматые тролли, визжа. Вниз сорвались, как потоки дождя...
Я склоняюсь к ответу D [шт], но в ключах к тестам ответ B [ж].
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться! Заранее спасибо за ответы.


ДОЖДЬ, дождя, мн. дожди, дождям \ в форме дождь – до[шт’] и до[ш’]; в остальных формах: дождя, дождю... – до[жд’]я и допуст. старш. до[ж’ж’]я .ВИЗЖАТЬ, визжу, визжит \ ви[жж]ать и допуст. старш. ви[ж’ж’]ать, в беглой речи возможно ви[ж]ать и ви[ж’]ать (! неправ. ви[зж]ать).  ПЕРЕСЕЧЕНИЕ только для ви[ж’ж’]а  и до[ж’ж’]я. Это и есть ответ: мягкий удлиненный ж’ж Там смазано, плохо видно.

Большой орфоэпический словарь  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=визжать&mode=slovari&dicts[]=49

• Вот что пишет "Грамота" (вопрос №294172, 14.08.2017):

Когда-то, действительно, произношение [дощ] признавалось единственно правильным, позднее – предпочтительным. Но эти времена давно прошли. Сейчас словари фиксируют два варианта: [дошть] и [дощ]. Оба являются нормативными, но рекомендуемое для эфира произношение – уже [дошть]. Вариант [дощ] постепенно уходит из языка.

• Вот какие разъяснения дают филологи МГУ:

По старомосковским нормам сочетание жд в слове дождь должно было произноситься как [ш':] (в результате оглушения на конце слова звонкого долгого согласного [ж':]), то же самое происходило с этим сочетанием в производных от слова дождь словах: дождя [даж':`а]...
Однако под влиянием того, как пишутся эти слова (их орфографии), в современном русском литературном языке развилось произношение сочетания жд в указанных словах как [жд'] (на конце слова соответственно [шт']: дождя [дажд'`а]...
Оба варианта прозношения входят в настоящее время орфоэпическую норму русского литературного языка на равноправных началах.

• Странный какой-то тест, небрежно оформленный (цитата вообще никак не выделена, поэтому в самом конце "нарисовались" четыре точки; после "визжа" нужна запятая).
Если произносить ближе к рифме, то ответ таков: [ж':].
Если же произносить соответственно рекомендации, то [жд'].

В тесте нет правильного варианта ответа.
Слово дождя должно рифмоваться с визжа, которое во времена Блока произносилось с долгим (удвоенным) мягким ж: ви[ж’ж’а].
Такое же «ж» должно было бы быть и в слове дождя: до[ж’ж’а].
В тесте ошибка: в варианте В) отсутствует знак мягкости у долгого «ж».
